# How do I differentiate between Apache Tomcat serving up a 404 and my application on tomcat returning a 404?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat7

I have a Java/Spring application, and I'm using Spring's Rest Template to call a webservice hosted on an apache tomcat container, and I would like to know how I can differentiate between the tomcat container serving up a 404 page (when an application is not deployed for example) and when my webservice returns a 404 (say when I cannot find an account/resource). Am I forced to look into the payload and fish out the "Apache Tomcat" html string that is returned? Or is there a better way to distinguish these? (Ie. a setting on the tomcat server that exposes a header value that might tell me that this is an application container specific error?)

The versions that we use are listed below.

- Tomcat 7.0.63 with JDK 8
- Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE / Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE

Thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: Well... how would you differentiate between these things with your human brain? Seems like your web service already returns e.g. 404 when it's unhappy. All other 404s are therefore coming from Tomcat, right?

Comment: How about the headers (content-type, etc.)? Could be different in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header may help to distinguish both.

tomcat response to http://localhost:8080/asd
***Content-Length: 0***

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2018 00:32:57 GMT
```

manager app response to http://localhost:8080/manager/htmll
***Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1***
***Content-Length: 1534***

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1534
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2018 00:39:10 GMT
```